# How to Create a classes for 2 different target platforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-mobile

I have 2 projects- one that is a web service and the other is a windows mobile application that queries that webservice.

Say for instance I have a class called 'Animal'. I want to use the webservice to return an instance of an Animal to the mobile device. The problem being that the mobile device obviously doesnt support the full .net framework, and the class Animal has some features that require the full framework.

What are my best options here? The class Animal will really only contain properties that are just text. Am I best parsing the data into an XML message and sending this back to the mobile device (so not actually using the Animal object on the mobile device?) or do I create 2 classes, one for each platform?

Thanks

Comment: Creating 2 classes will severely affect maintainability. Consider XML or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can share a code file between two projects. Right click your project, choose Add -> Existing item, and then click the down arrow next to the Add button, you will see a "Add as Link" option there, if you know you class will compile for both projects even if they target different platforms, you can use this to share the class for both projects

Answer (score 0):

I run Windows and Mobile using the same code.

Mobile devices have the word `PocketPC` defined in the Project's Properties, therefore, all you have to do (since you are coding in C#) is:

```
public static bool CreateDirectoryWithPermission(string path) {
  bool ok = false;
  DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
#if !PocketPC
  try {
    DirectorySecurity ds;
    if (dir.Exists) {
      ds = dir.GetAccessControl();
    } else {
      ds = dir.Parent.GetAccessControl();
    }
    string user = Environment.UserDomainName + @"\" + Environment.UserName;
    FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(user, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
    ds.AddAccessRule(rule);
    dir.Create(ds);
    ok = true;
  } catch (Exception) { }
#endif
  if (!ok) {
    try {
      dir.Create();
      ok = true;
    } catch (Exception) { }
  }
  return ok;
}
```

If I remember correctly, `System.Security.AccessControl` is not defined under Windows Mobile, so the `DirectorySecurity` is undefined.

**UPDATE:**

Here is another way to do what you are interested in: Create a Serializable class in a completely separate namespace, use that namespace in both projects, and pass the serialized data from the Webservice to the Mobile device. I do that, as well, but there is more code.

```
namespace LocksAnimal {

  [Serializable()]
  public class Animal {

    private string name;

    public Animal() {
      name = "Lock";
    }

    public string GetName() {
#ifdef PocketPC
      return name + " (Mobile Version)";
#else
      return name + " (Webservice Version)";
#endif
    }

  }

}
```

The Webservice version, of course, can access more detailed information (like `GetAccessControl()` shown in the first code segment).

I hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Whoops! I just realized you are asking how to pass an OBJECT, not code for both environments. Kindly post a note after you've had a chance to look over this and let me know if you'd like it to stay or have it deleted. It still has useful info for coding 1 class for different formats.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response, although i'm still unsure of how I should do this. So, I have say an 'Animal' object on the web service. I want to pass this object back to the mobile device. I don't want to have to create 2 classes (one that is a mobile version and one that is compatible on the web service). Is their a way? I know i can serialize the data through JSON or something, but then the data won't really be an object of the same class when it reaches the device

Comment: You may need to write your class to exclude things specific to your WebServer, then create a special webserver class that derives from the base class. When you serialize, only serialize the base class. Does that make sense?